# Can GraphQL Queries be named, kind of like stored procedures, and reused?

Tags: graphql

I'm building a Graphene-Django based GraphQL API.  One of my colleagues, who is building an Angular client that will use the API, has asked if there's a way to store frequently used queries somehow on the server-side so that he can just call them by name?

I have not yet encountered such functionality so am not sure if it's even possible.

FYI he is using the Apollo Client so maybe such "named" queries is strictly client-side?  Here's a page he referred me to: http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/cache-updates.html

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent question! I think the thing you are looking for is called "persisted queries." The GraphQL spec only outlines

- A Type System for a schema
- A formal language for queries
- How to validate/execute a query against a schema

Beyond that, it is up to the implementation to make specific optimizations. There are a few ways to do persisted queries, and different ones may be more or less helpful for your project.

**Storing Queries as a String**

Queries can easily be stored as Strings, and the convention is to use *.gql files to do that. Many editors/IDEs will even have syntax highlighting for this. To consume them later, just URL Encode them, and you're all set! Since these strings are "known" you can whitelist the requests on the server if you choose.

```
const myQuery = `
  {
    user {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`

const query = `www.myserver.com/query=${urlEncode(myQuery)}`
```

**Persisted Queries**

For a more sophisticated approach, you can take queries that are extracted from your project (either from strings or using a build tool), pre-run them and put the result in a DB. This is what Facebook does. There are plenty of tools out there to help you with this, and the [Awesome-GraphQL](https://github.com/chentsulin/awesome-graphql) repo is a good place to start looking.

**Resources**

[Check out this blog for more info on Persisted Queries](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/persisted-graphql-queries-with-apollo-client-119fd7e6bba5)

Comment: I looked, but could not find, Django specific instructions of what needs to be changed on the server to support Persisted Queries on the client.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you asked this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224911/how-to-configure-graphene-django-to-work-with-persisted-queries